# what is state parameter in mapStateToProps in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner to React-Redux. I want to understand the `state` parameter in `mapStateToProps(state)`. Should we consider `state` our component state or  `Reducer State`? I really need to understand the behind-the-scenes of Redux.

**Code**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    course: state.course
  };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Redux` is basically a state management tool, there you have a `centralized` `store`, which basically is similar to you `component` state but different because here its not only component specific data, its application wide data. Where you components can access this `store` to get them the piece of data they need.

function `mapStateToProps` acts just as its name suggests, it maps out `store` data to our component props, that is how you get the data from the redux store, via props. So in your case,

I suppose your `store` object is something like this,

```
{ course : { courseId : 'A' , courseName : 'Maths' ...} }
```

what you are doing in mapStateToProps is, mapping your `store` data to component props, so the `state` passed to `mapStateToProps` is actually the `store`

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    course: state.course
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank You for reply , I am really confuse where this `state.course` is comming

Comment: so basically it comes when you connect you component to the redux store,

`export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent));`

like so. let me know if you still don't get it.

Comment: Thanks, it really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

So here is the answer

state inside the mapStateToProps gets all the state of store 
So let say you have these

```
books:[{
}],
chairs:{
  ...
},
table:{}
```

these 3 states in store mapStateToProps will have all of these states, so to use a specific state in component you can extract that from state variable passed to mapStateToProps

In your case you need just course state in your component so you are getting that only

Let me know if you need more explanation

Answer (score 2):

> I mean should we consider state as our component local state or we referring this state as Reducer State

Per the [Redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#state), the `state` argument contains the entire Redux Store state.

> The first argument to a `mapStateToProps` function is the entire Redux store state (the same value returned by a call to store.getState()).

Answer (score 0):

`state` which is passed to `mapStateToProps` as your first argument, is your entire redux store that consists of different pieces of states from your reducers. As listed in redux [Docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#state)

> The first argument to a **mapStateToProps** function is the **entire Redux
>   store state** (the same value returned by a call to store.getState()).
>   Because of this, the first argument is traditionally just called
>   state. (While you can give the argument any name you want, calling it
>   store would be incorrect - it's the "state value", not the "store
>   instance".)
>
> The mapStateToProps function should always be written with at least
>   state passed in.

Hope this helps !